# setting int drawable resource to onClick

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on a quiz app of 10 questions whereby i need to display 5 images at selected question fields an alert dialog as a hint when a text is clicked. 
I have set drawable resource files to display each individual image to referred text. How do i properly set the resource drawable int to the text when clicked?
For now, am getting an error.

**QuestionLibrary.java**

```
// This file contains questions from QuestionBank
class QuestionLibrary {
    // array of questions
    private String mQuestions [] = {
            "Question1",
            "Question2",
            "Question3",
            "Question4?",
            "Qustion5",
            "Question6",
            "Question7",
            "Question8",
            "Question9",
            "Question10"

    };
    // array of multiple choices for each question
    private String mChoices [][] = {
           // choices goes here
    };
    //setting images
    public static int[] image_drawables  = new int[] {
R.drawable_01, R.drawable_02, R.drawable_03, R.drawable_04

    };

    // array of correct answers - in the same order as array of questions
private String mCorrectAnswers[] = {
           Answers goes here
};

// text to show hint reference
    private static String[] click_me_text = {
      "", "", "Hint", "", "Hint", "", "", "Click me!", "Click me!", "", "", 

    };

    // method returns click_me text from array textQuestions[] based on array index
    String getTextHint(int a) {
        return click_me_text[a];
    }
    // method returns number of questions
    int getLength(){
        return mQuestions.length;
    }

    // method returns question from array textQuestions[] based on array index
    String getQuestion(int a) {
        return mQuestions[a];
    }

    // method return a single multiple choice item for question based on array index,
    // based on number of multiple choice item in the list - 1, 2, 3 or 4 as an argument
    String getChoice(int index, int num) {
        return mChoices[index][num-1];
    }

    //  method returns correct answer for the question based on array index
    String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
        return mCorrectAnswers[a];
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();
    //initializing buttons
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    TextView msingleQuestion;
    TextView mQuestion; //current question to answer
    TextView mClickMe; // text to be clicked which should display image
    private int mQuestionNumber = 0; // current question number
    private String mAnswer;  // correct answer for question in mQuestionView
    private int mquizNumber = 1;
    private int mfailedQuestions = 5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begineer);
        // set textViews here
        msingleQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleQuestion);
        mQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
        mClickMe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.click_me);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstOption);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondOption);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.thirdOption);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fourthOption);
        updateQuestion(); //update question
        // setting respective animations for the buttons
        blinkClickMe();

    }

    private void blinkClickMe() {
        Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(60);
        anim.setStartOffset(30);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        mClickMe.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    private void updateQuizNumber(int mquizNumber) {
        msingleQuestion.setText("" + mquizNumber+"/"+mQuestionLibrary.getLength());
    }


    private void updateQuestion() {
        // check if we are not outside array bounds for questions
        if(mQuestionNumber<mQuestionLibrary.getLength() ){
            // set text for hint and click_me
            mClickMe.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getTextHint(mQuestionNumber));
            // set the text for new question, and new 4 alternative to answer on four buttons
            mQuestion.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
            button1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 1));
            button2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 2));
            button3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 3));
            button4.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber,4));
            mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
            mQuestionNumber++;
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(BeginnerActivity.this, "It was the last question!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuOptions.class);
//            intent.putExtra("score", mScore); // pass the current score to the second screen
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        //all logic for all answers buttons in one method
        final Button answer = (Button) view;
        // if the answer is correct, increase the score
        if (answer.getText().equals(mAnswer) ){
            answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            // blink correct answer
            Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            anim.setDuration(60);
            anim.setStartOffset(30);
            anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT);
            answer.startAnimation(anim);

        }else   {
            answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            mfailedQuestions--;
            updateLives(mfailedQuestions);
        }
        if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
            // once user answer the question, we move on to the next one, if any
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        answer.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.rounded_button_questions));
                    }

                    updateQuestion();
                    mquizNumber++;
                    updateQuizNumber(mquizNumber);
                }

            }, 1000);


        } else {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BeginnerActivity.this, MenuOptions.class);
//            intent.putExtra("score", mScore); // pass the current score to the second screen
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }, 1000);

        }

    }

    public void revealImage(View view) {
        loadImage();

    }

    private void loadImage() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
// what is needed here?
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(QuestionLibrary.image_drawables[mQuestionNumber], null);
        builder.setView(dialogView)
                .create().show();
    }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText("time's up!!");
            Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            anim.setDuration(60);
            anim.setStartOffset(30);
            anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT);
            timer.startAnimation(anim);
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    finish();
                }

            }, 500);
        }


    }
}
```

> **Error** FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.benkeys.pianoquizgame, PID: 3961
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
>                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>                                                                                             Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/beginner_04.png from xml type layout resource
>   ID #0x7f060056
>                                                                                                at
>   android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:990)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2103)
>                                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1115)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.example.benkeys.pianoquizgame.BeginnerActivity.loadImage(BeginnerActivity.java:244)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.example.benkeys.pianoquizgame.BeginnerActivity.revealImage(BeginnerActivity.java:237)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
>                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>                                                                                             Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Corrupt XML binary file
>                                                                                                at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)

Comment: WHAT YOU NEED EXACTLY??

Comment: i need to set int drawable xml's on my textview to display image in dialog when clicked

Comment: why are you adding image to textview, you can use image view in dialog box to show them.

Comment: just create customer view with those image views and set them in alert dialog or dialog fragment with necessary listeners

Comment: so no need to inflate layout with layout inflater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach :

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable)
```

set your drawable object in **res/Drawable** and get it by code above and put in your dialog box.

if you have more than one drawable use **switch()** method like this:

```
switch(answeredQuestion)
{
case 1:
 //show considered dialog box
break;
case 2:
// show considered dialog box
break;
...
case 10:
//show considered dialog box
default 
break;
}
```

Comment: i actually have more than one drawable xml for each image

Comment: so no need to inflate layout with layout inflater?

Comment: Builder.serView()